# Errors while using Libtorch + OpenCV + QT Creator

Tags: c++, opencv, qt-creator, libtorch

I have the following configuration in the .pro file

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt
CONFIG += thread

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv4
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/
LIBS += -lopencv_core
LIBS += -lopencv_highgui
LIBS += -lopencv_imgproc
LIBS += -lopencv_videoio

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0

INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/libtorch/include
INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include
LIBS += -L/path/to/libtorch/lib
LIBS += -ltorch -lc10
```

OpenCV works absolutely fine **without** "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=**0**". With this, however, I get this following errors:

[image]

OpenCV works fine **with** "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=**1**" as well. But it throws a different set of errors:

[image]

Setting "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=**0**" has been recommended for Libtorch in most of the forums to avoid the errors above.

What could be a solution or some solutions to work around this?
(I am a newbie to both Libtorch and Qt Creator.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe OpenCV and Libtorch were compiled with a different version of GCC (and different values of _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI).

Try recompiling them by yourself and see if things change.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **you downloaded the wrong ABI version of LibTorch**. It looks like that you downloaded the *Pre-CXX11 ABI* version of LibTorch, while OpenCV is compiled with *CXX11 ABI*. So if you set `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`, OpenCV throws errors, and if you set `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1`, LibTorch throws errors.

Download the CXX11 ABI LibTorch from PyTorch official website and you won't need to set the `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` flag.

[image: Select CXX11 ABI]

About the **dual ABI** problem of GCC, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html